# Unable to upgrade Flutter - Error: cache.dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I was on channel beta and trying to apply `flutter doctor` but I got the following error after it was trying to upgrade flutter. I deleted the cache folder and tried it again but it did not work. Even when I try `flutter channel stable` I get the same error.

```
> Downloading Dart SDK from Flutter engine
> 641a7a3d8e59c2fbe18a79ab844d4a017ab6560e...   % Total    % Received %
> Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
>                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed 100  217M  100  217M    0     0   702k      0  0:05:16  0:05:16
> --:--:--  772k Building flutter tool... flutter/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/cache.dart:480:1: Error: The
> '===' operator is not supported.
> ======= ^ flutter/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/cache.dart:480:4: Error: The '===' operator is not supported.
> =======    ^ flutter/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/cache.dart:479:1: Error: Operator declarations must be preceded by the keyword
> 'operator'. Try adding the keyword 'operator'. <<<<<<< HEAD ^^
> flutter/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/cache.dart:479:1: Error: A
> method declaration needs an explicit list of parameters. Try adding a
> parameter list to the method declaration. <<<<<<< HEAD ^^
> flutter/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/cache.dart:479:3: Error:
> Expected '{' before this. <<<<<<< HEAD   ^^
> flutter/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/cache.dart:479:1: Error:
> Operator '<<' should have exactly one parameter. <<<<<<< HEAD ^^
> flutter/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/cache.dart:479:3: Error:
> Operator declarations must be preceded by the keyword 'operator'. Try
> adding the keyword 'operator'. <<<<<<< HEAD   ^^
> flutter/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/cache.dart:479:3: Error: A
> method declaration needs an explicit list of parameters. Try adding a
> parameter list to the method declaration. <<<<<<< HEAD   ^^
> flutter/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/cache.dart:479:5: Error:
> Expected '{' before this. <<<<<<< HEAD
>     ^^ flutter/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/cache.dart:479:3: Error: Operator '<<' should have exactly one parameter. <<<<<<< HEAD   ^^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by downloading the stable [Flutter](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos) package and replacing it with my existing version. The problem was caused by VS Code trying to change the flutter files.